# Python: how to vectorized insertions of values into list/np.array (with given probability)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, insert, vectorization

I have very long numpy array:

```
v = np.array([10, 15, 15, 15, 10, 30, 30, 10, 10])
```

And I want to insert 0s after each element with probability

```
stop_prob = 0.5
```

So result could look like:

```
[ 0 10  0  0 15  0  0 15 15 10  0  0 30 30 10 10  0  0]
```

Here is my code:

```
v_new = []
for j in range(len(v)+1):
    choice = np.random.choice([1, 0], p=[1-stop_prob, stop_prob])
    while choice == 0:
        v_new.append(0)
        choice = np.random.choice([1, 0], p=[1-stop_prob, stop_prob])
    if j != len(v):
        v_new.append(v[j])
```

It works but takes a lot of time for very big list (with millions of values). How can I vectorize this algorithm?

Here is my attempt to vectorize:

```
idx = np.random.choice([1, 0], size=len(v), p=[1-stop_prob, stop_prob])
v = np.insert(v, idx, 0)
```

But result is incorrect:

```
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 10  0 15 15 15 10 30 30 10 10]
```

It puts all zeros in the beginning of the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prepend `0s` to each element of `v` with probability `p = stop_prob` until you insert the element, then this is a sequence of **independent Bernoulli trials**.

You can model the random variable "number of 0's before each element" as a [Negative Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution), to count the number of "failures" (0s), before getting exactly `1` "success", with success probability `1 - p`:

```
# number of zeros we will prepend to each element
# note: use len(v) + 1 if we want trailing zeros, like the original algorithm
num_zeros = np.random.negative_binomial(1, 1 - stop_prob, len(v))

# indices where we will place the elements of v
idx = np.arange(0, len(num_zeros)) # original indices
idx += np.cumsum(num_zeros) # we make space for the zeros

# we build the final array
# note: use (np.max(idx),) if we want trailing zeros
v_new = np.zeros((np.max(idx) + 1,), dtype = v.dtype)
v_new[idx[:len(v)]] = v
```

One run example:

```
>>> num_zeros
array([1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
>>> v_new
array([ 0, 10, 15,  0,  0,  0, 15, 15, 10, 30, 30,  0, 10, 10])
```